# Xamarin form : Token authentication with xamarin form web api

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I am working with token based authentication for xamarin form here is my code

```
 public async Task<string> checkLogin(string username, string password)
    {




    var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",password),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","password")


    };
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://softsol.com.pk/Token");

    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

    var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    JObject jdynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
    var accessToken = jdynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
    var refershToken = jdynamic.Value<string>("refresh_token");
    var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    var accessTokenExpiration= jdynamic.Value< DateTime> (".expires");


    //await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", content, "OK");
    Debug.WriteLine(content);
    Settings.AccessToken=accessToken;
    Settings.RefreshToken = refershToken;

    Settings.AccessTokenexpiration = accessTokenExpiration;
    return accessToken;
    //return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;



}
```

when I login with usernamre and password I get this error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0
```

and if I run in postman its working fine for example if I run this http://softsol.com.pk/Token in postman with username="test",password="test", grant-type="password" I get the token and its working but I get error from xamarin form. And I am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

I visited the API part of your backend at http://softsol.com.pk/Help and I discovered that http://softsol.com.pk/Token is not there.
Moreover, testing on Postman returns a JSON response  :

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

With postman, I sent requests both in JSON:

```
{"username":"test","password":"test","grant-type":"password"}
```

and as a x-www-form-urlencoded :
[image]

I suggest you have to debug properly and analyze the Exemption information.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public async void GetInfoLogin()
    {

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> member = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", UserName.Text),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", PassWord.Text),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("action", "get_user")
        };


        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(member);

        HttpClient client = new HttpCLient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync("(endpoint to server)",content);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var TReturn = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        var success = TReturn.Value<string>("success");
        var error = TReturn.Value<string>("error");
        var user_id = TReturn.Value<string>("user_id");
        var full_name = TReturn.Value<string>("full_name");
        var time = TReturn.Value<int>("time");      
        var send = TReturn.Value<string>("send");
```

}

Comment: please explain what your code does and how it solve the problem

Comment: it send the location and token and action to the server , if it right infomation , server will send the information you need to the application , it's like a simple login when you send a right user name and password , the server will let you login into the app